# Convert "null" into np.nan when decoding json in python dataclass

Tags: python, json, json-deserialization, python-dataclasses

Suppose I have a dataclass that looks something like this:

```
from dataclasses_json import DataClassJsonMixin
from dataclasses import dataclass

class ToyDataclass(DataClassJsonMixin):
    name: str
    value: float
```

The `value` field can be `np.nan`, which is meaningful in my setting. Sometimes, I need to read these from serialized format, where the `np.nan` cases are being stored as such:
`'{"name": "testname", "value": null}'`. The problem is that when I deserialize, `null` is converted to `None` instead of `np.nan`.

My goal is to write a custom deserializer that simply treats every `null` as a `np.nan`. I have tried and failed to do this a few times. For example, this does not work (it simply deserializes as `None`, like before):

```
from dataclasses_json import DataClassJsonMixin, config
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
class ToyDataclass(DataClassJsonMixin):
    name: str
    value: float = field(
        metadata=config(
            decoder=(lambda val: np.nan if val is None else val),
        )
    )
```

Also, I can't control that the serialized dataclass have `"null"` in them instead of `"NaN"` for the `nan`s. This is a constraint I have to work around in my codebase. Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Comment: Could you solve this?

Comment: Still an issue in 0.6.1

Answer (score 0):

I think this is completely unsupported or is a current bug as of dataclasses-json 0.6.1. I have filed an issue https://github.com/lidatong/dataclasses-json/issues/497